# Is anyone using SpringSource tc server as a Tomcat replacement?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee

It looks like SpringSource [has just released a GA version](http://www.springsource.org/node/1385) of their [tc Server](http://www.springsource.com/products/tcserver) application server.

It sounds from their description like it is a drop-in replacement for Apache Tomcat, with better "enterprise capabilities", such as "advanced diagnostics", better operations management, deployment, etc. (and of course, the support that they want to sell you as their primary business model).

So I'm curious (and I'm not sure if this is truly a SO question), but is anyone using tc Server today in any shape or fashion? Has it worked out well for you? Did you find whatever features they are adding to Tomcat to be worth it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I see it, the primary advantage of tcServer is in managing large clusters of load-balanced tomcats. Aside from the management/monitoring layer (which is very cool, by the way), it also has a faster database connection pooling mechanism, and a generally tweaked configuration optimised for high volume.  Other than that, it's just Tomcat.

Answer (score 6):

They've just released a [developer edition](http://www.springsource.com/products/tcserver/devedition). Have a look at this [screencast](http://s3.springsource.com/MRKT/spring-metrics/Spring_Insight_Preview-final2.mov) which demonstrates how their diagnostics work.

Answer (score 3):

MuleSoft released [Tcat Server](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat-server-enterprise-tomcat-application-server), which provides advanced provisioning, Tomcat and webapp specific diagnostics. Some of the key differences with tcserver is that Tcat Server is 100% unmodified Apache Tomcat and the diagnostics are built right into the product.

Disclosure: I work for MuleSoft, and would be happy to answer any questions on Tcat Server.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also add that the "advanced monitoring" capabilities are actually available in java 1.5 (check the JDK's SNMP/JMX docs).  Been using it for years with rrdtool and recently ported over to using highcharts+mongo.